# Mysql MATCH/AGAINST on WITH clause?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I have a MySQL query where I want to use a MATCH AGAINST on the result of a WITH clause, like this:

```
WITH (select stuff from somewhere)
WHERE MATCH(somefield) AGAINST(' +"term_a" +"term_b"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, that generates an error `[HY000][1214] The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Is there a way to use MATCH against the results of a WITH clause? The MATCH/AGAINST does work against the tables themselves if I unroll the WITH, so that's not a problem. It's only a problem when I use the WITH.

Comment: FYI, that's called a CTE (Common Table Expression). It's not a real table, it doesn't have any indexes, so you can't use full-text searching on it.

Comment: By the way, This is the way CTE is defined ? Must be like this : WITH cte_name AS (.......) SELECT ... bla bla :